# Lutron Skylark SCL-153P dimmer wiring help

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I have installed two Lutron Skylark SCL-153P dimmers. The one on the left works and other does not. For both dimmers, I have connected black to black, green to ground (copper wire), red and white to pink and both reds to a common white.

[image]

In addition, can I remove the tabs on the dimmers so they fit better in the box?

Comment: What do you mean by "both reds to a common white"?  Is this a 3-way switch setup, and if so, how was it wired before?  Is it possible to roll it back to previous config with the old switches *such that it 100% works*?  I'm keenly interested in which wires are 3-way *travelers* (2 wires on brass screws on the old switch) and whether all 3 switch wires connected to the same cable.  Note that in 3-way circuits, wire colors are meaningless.

Comment: Are both dimmers trying to control the same light, or different lights?

Comment: Remove as few tabs as possible. The instructions will describe exactly how downrated the load will be with tab removal. Depending on what you're controlling, you might choose to put the toggle in the middle and leave all the tabs.